# Understanding the grammar of "Nul n'aurait pu le dire"

Tags: négation

I believe I understand the meaning of "Nul n'aurait pu le dire", but I'm unsure about the grammar.

First of all, am I correct in thinking that *aurait pu* is the *plus-que-parfait*?

Second, why is there nothing to complete the negation? I would have expected something like:

> Nul n'aurait **pas** pu le dire

In other words, why is there no *pas* (or something similar) to complete it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- the verbal form "aurait pu" is an instance of *conditionnel passé*. The (indicative) *plus-que-parfait* would have been "avait pu"
- "Nul" used as pronoun is a more formal form of "personne" (in the meaning of "no one"). "Nul", just like "personne", already carries the negation , so there is no need to add the adverb "pas". It would be an error.

Actually, "nul n'aurait pas pu le dire" is very awkward semantically as it is a case of *double negative*, which in French equates to a positive (logically, "nul n'aurait pas pu le dire" should actually mean "no one would have been unable to tell", which at best is just the opposite of what "nul n'aurait pu le dire" means). In any case, this is not a turn of phrase that a native speaker would use.

Comment: *Nul* est sûrement équivalent, au sens large, à *Pas une personne* : *Pas une personne n'aurait pu le dire* ou dit autrement *Quelle qu'elle soit, aucune personne n'aurait pu le dire*.

Comment: Le propos sur la *double négation* avec *pas* (adverbe) est un peu insensé, inadapté : le verbe est associé à *personne* et l'adverbe a un rôle essentiellement sémantique.

Comment: Admettons... dans cette hypothèse,  que signifierait alors "nul n'aurait pas pu le dire" ? La même chose que "nul n'aurait pu le dire ? "

Comment: Nul n'aurait pu dire = aucune personne n'aurait pu dire. Nul n'aurait pas pu dire = aucune personne n'aurait pas pu dire => toute personne aurait pu dire. Où est le problème ?

Comment: Cela est aussi sensé que de dire *Le néant n'aurait pas pu exister* : le verbe ne peut se réaliser au niveau sémantique sans personne.

Comment: Nous sommes d'accord que la phrase "nul n'aurait pas pu dire" n'a pas grand sens (ou du moins, pas le sens attendu par l'auteur de la question) et ne sera pas prononcée par un locuteur natif; c'était le sens de mon commentaire.  Je le modifie pour clarifier ce point.

Answer (score 2):

No native speaker.

> Nul n'aurait pu le dire

'aurait pu' is the third singular of the so-called conditionnel du passé.  See
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel_pass%C3%A9_(conjugaison_fran%C3%A7aise)

The sentence, as it stands, conveys the meaning of the sentences

> No one could have said it. No one could have said that. No one could have said so.

Regarding the absence of 'pas'.  Pas is not needed with the negative singular indefinite pronoun 'nul' (pronom indéfini singulier).

> Nul n'aurait pu le dire.

> Nul argument ne pourrait la convaincre ; nul n'est censé ignorer la loi

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nul#Pronom_ind%C3%A9fini

Comment: L'expression *nul n'aurait pu le dire* est fortement connotée ; on ne peut pas remplacer le pronom indéfini par un pronom personnel.

Comment: C'est presque cela mais ce n'est pas encore exact. Peut-être comprendrez-vous mieux si on précise la réponse de Greg.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Merci:-)! Pourrais-tu me préciser ce qu'il manque ?

Comment: La phrase est constituée d'éléments grammaticaux, d'unités lexicales mais très divers ou variables qu'il faut apprendre à reconnaître ou identifier.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je crois que c'est mieux d'effacer ma réponse:-)!

Comment: Ouai mais attendez un peu...

Comment: Dans votre propos, vous n'avez pas saisi l'idée exprimée (le sens qui émerge de la phrase) comme en anglais par *be able to*.

Comment: Voilà, vous pouvez supprimer votre réponse ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Negation is expressed in various forms in a correlative way, with more or less evidence, without losing sight of the general meaning.

The following expressions have more or less the same meaning.

> **Nul ne** le sait.                     (pronom + ne)
> *Tous le savent.*
>
> **Personne ne** le sait.                (pronom + ne)
> *Quiconque le sait.*
>
> **Aucune** personne **ne** le sait.     (adj. + ne)
> *Chacun le sait.*
>
> **Pas** une personne **ne** le sait.    (adv. + ne)
> *Tout le monde le sait.*

Various words convey a negative meaning and form the negation when associated with *ne*.

**Note:** The negation can also be expressed with a single word (ne) in which case the negation focuses on the verb.

Comment: @Greg: Voici le complément de votre réponse !

Comment: @Dimitris: Cette réponse vous intéressera peut-être.